# Schengen 90/180 day rule for residence permit holder of another Schengen country

Tags: schengen

On a given day, I travel from a Schengen zone country where I have a residence permit to a Schengen zone country where I don't have a residence permit. Does that day count as one of my 90/180 days?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes, but this isn't necessarily strictly enforced.  If you live in a Schengen country and work in the same Schengen country but travel through a second Schengen country in your daily commute, nobody is going to count this against you even though there is no explicit provision for this sort of thing in the Schengen codes.

Comment: It isn't a commute, it's just a move from one country to another on that day. So I guess it is subtracted from 90/180.

Comment: Again, strictly speaking, yes.  But it's difficult to think of circumstances in which one day is going to make a practical difference -- or even a few days.

Comment: What does 90/180 days mean? Why do you have 90/180 days?

Comment: @André 90/180 days is the Schengen rule about maximum presence, you can only stay in Schengen (RPs excluded) for a maximum of 90 days in a 180 days window

Comment: That's a rule for some tourists, the op is a resident.

Comment: "It should be noted that periods of previous stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa are not taken
into account in the calculation of the duration of visa-free stay. Residence permits and long-stay visas are subject to
different rules and the above explanations and calculations do not apply to them."

Comment: @André, when in a different country than the one where you have your residence you are still bound to the 90 out of 180 rules, even when not as strictly enforced.

Comment: @André What's “authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa” are stays *in the country that issued said residence permit or long-stay visa* and nowhere else. Without this provision a resident in a Schengen country wouldn't be allowed to visit other Schengen countries at all after their first 90 days in the area. So what this means is that resident in a Schengen country still have the full 90 days contingent available to them for stays in other Schengen countries, not that there are no limits whatsoever.

Comment: @André it's not explicit in the Schengen Borders Code, but it is explicit in the Schengen Acquis, article 21, which says "Aliens who hold valid residence permits issued by one of the Member States may, on the basis of that permit and a valid travel document, move freely for up to 90 days in any 180-day period within the territories of the other Member States, provided that they fulfil the entry conditions..."; see https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32010R0265 and https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32013R0610 for the relevant amendments.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the period of stay would be computed in the same way so that both the first and last day in which you spent time in other Schengen countries than your country of residence would count towards the 90/180 limit. Of course, you won't get stamps an enforcing this is not a priority.